# Ubuntu select option is not available at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, startup

I have installed Ubuntu 23.XX alongside Windows 10 on HP Envy laptop.
I can start Ubuntu, after opening Windows 10, going to boot->Advance options. But I don't see Ubuntu option at startup of my laptop under OS selection.
I see only Windows 10.
I tried to disable secure boot. It didn't work.
I typed Sudo commands to create/set Grub. It didn't work.
I also tried EasyBCD, it didn't give me option to select Ubuntu.
Is there any other solution available?